# text goes out of JTextArea although wrapping is enabled

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

**Problem:**
enabling wrapping on JTextArea is supposed to wrap the line; but it fails to do that sometimes.

**Expecting:** "ghijjj" is wrapped to the next line.

**What Happens Instead:**

JTextArea would not wrap "ghijjj" , instead it only barely shows 'g' and 'hijjj' will be out of the screen(viewport).

**Details**:

OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)

OS: Windows 10 v 1909

**SSCCE:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class ScrollableTextArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setSize(400, 300); //edit:per suggesstion
        JTextArea bodyArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
        bodyArea.setLineWrap(true);
        bodyArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane bodyScroller = new JScrollPane(bodyArea);
        bodyScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(bodyScroller);
        bodyArea.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b c d e f ghijjj");

        frame.pack(); // edit:per suggesstion
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Visually**:

[image: text going out of JTextArea]

I tried adding borders thinking the problem is with the JScrollPane, but it wasn't. So is this a bug related to the word-wrapping algorithm the JTextArea uses? Or maybe a problem with Java on Windows?
And is there any solution?

**UPDATES**:

- It works fine on Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
  (although the ***window*** and the ***font size*** are smaller than on JDK11)

Comment: `frame.setSize(400, 300); .. frame.setVisible(true);` should be `.. frame.pack(); frame.setVisible(true);`. The 400 x 300 is no better than a guess, and likely messing things up. BTW - I could not reproduce the effect here (using a different JRE) but in any case, pack your GUI and see if that works better.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did as you said, and no it didn't work.

Comment: Show the updated code as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: For me, windows 10, java 8 it works fine: https://i.imgur.com/4BcpOpc.png

Comment: "is there any solution?" Stop typing long strings with no spaces, or make the JTextArea much wider.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc and don't shoot myself in the foot =))).

Comment: @GeorgeZ. trying removing a few 'a' one-by-one from your text, does it still work?

Comment: @psychob Yes. You can give it a try with Java 8.

Comment: *Steps to reproduce::* - that code should be part of the [mre]. That is you use setText(…) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Weird...it works on java 8!!!

Comment: @camickr Hah..Thanks. Though at first I thought it could only happen if a user types it.